# Eclipse Error: "Type safety: The expression of type ArrayList needs unchecked conversion to conform to ArrayList<String[]>"

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a warning I am trying to resolve. This is the code:

```
ArrayList<String[]> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
```

Eclipse highlights "new ArrayList<>()" with the following warning:

> Type safety: The expression of type `ArrayList` needs unchecked conversion to conform to `ArrayList<String[]>`

I think I have declared the `ArrayList` correctly. It looks like the warning is telling me to only insert the type `String[]` into parameters, which the code is doing. Any suggestions?

Comment: "This code" where, specifically? It works without warnings for me (in Intellij).

Comment: Cannot reproduce..

Comment: I am using Eclipse. The warning is on the declaration of the new ArrayList, specifically highlighting "new ArrayList<>()".

Comment: If only the first line is relevant, please remove the other lines.

Comment: It seems that it is a problem with settings. This suggestion seems to be from before Java 1.7, which introduced the diamond operator.

Comment: @bicycle_guy it should be ArrayList<String[]> parameters = new ArrayList(); i am getting above warning for the same.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?